# Getting data out of a select box and passing it into params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing this for a school project and it is not working. :(
How do I get out the selected[petowner_id] from the view and make it usable in a ruby controller?
How do I make the @selected_pet = params([petowner_id]) in the controller that comes in from the view to function? Currently it renders an error message when I try to set it. :(
I am getting very tired of it not working.

The controller from Pets controller

```
class PetsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /pets
  # GET /pets.json

  def monsters
    #Finds the current user
    if current_user
       @user = current_user
       @pets_kept = [] #why?
       #@petowner = Petowner.find(params[:petowner][:id])
       #if(params[:commit])
       #end
       @monster = "Eeeep"
       @mypets=[]
       @all_my_pets = @user.petowners
#options value = 2

#params { selected_petowner[petowner_id]}
       @selectpet = params{[selected][petowner_id]}
       @petowner = Petowner.find_by_id(params[:id])
       @pet = Pet.find_by_id(params[:pet_id])
       #Find the petowners that the user currently has
       #@mypets = @user.petowners

       #This is my way of doing things in a C++ fashion, I don't get all ruby things
       @user.petowners.each do |pet|
           #@selected_pet = pet.find(params[:selected])
       #   if pet.hp != 0
       #      @pets_kept << pet #Dont recall seeing the << before in ruby but for C++ statement used for cout statements
             #if pet.select
             #   @selected_pet = pet.select
             #end
          end
       #@selected_pet = Petowner.find(params[:petowner][:selected])
       #end
       @selected_pet = 1 #@user.petowners.find(params[:id])

       @mypets = current_user.petowners.select{|pet| pet.hp !=0}
       #raise "I am here"
       #@selected_pet = @mypets.find(params[:id][:selected])
       #@mypets = @pets_kept
    end
```

The code from the view that doesn't go back to the controller variable and set it. :(

```
<select id="petowner_id" name="selected[petowner_id]">
         <%= @all_my_pets.each do |pet| %>
            <option value="<%= pet.id %>"><%= pet.pet_name %></option>
         <% end %>
      </select>
```

Previous step from pets/monsters view that doesn't work at all from previous collection. :(

```
<%= form_for :petowner, :url => petowner_fights_path(@selected_pet, @pet) do |f| %>

               <p>Select a pet <%#= f.collection_select(:petowner, :petowner_id, @user.petowners, :petowner_id, :pet_name) %></p>
               <%= render 'monsterinfo' %>

               <div class="outer"></div>
               <%= f.submit "Fight Selected Monster" %>
            <% end %>
```

Comment: `params{[selected][petowner_id]}` is invalid syntax. I think you need `params[:petowner_id]`.

Comment: Okay I tried this syntax @selectpet = params[:petowner][:id] but it is not working. I am getting the error:  NoMethodError in PetsController#monsters

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Rails.root: /home/eric/tobenamed.git/Trial
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/pets_controller.rb:20:in `monsters'

Request

Parameters:

None

Show session dump

Show env dump
Response

Headers:

None

Comment: Well that's not exactly what I suggested you try. ;) But to be sure, you could look at the dump of the params hash when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `params[:petowner][:petowner_id]`. Definitely don't construct the select with html in a view.

By the way, it's really helpful to see all of the params passed in to a controller action. I tend to `raise params.to_yaml` when I need to do that.

Comment: *Sigh.* I am never going to get the params from a select box to work. :( I tried this and it gives me a dumb error message. :(

Comment: Did you raise params? It should be an error message. It would tell you what's contained in params.

Comment: I am raising the params on ln 25 but I am getting this error:  NoMethodError in PetsController#monsters

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Parameters:

None

Show session dump

Show env dump
Response

Headers:

None    On ln 17 when I raise the message I get this:  RuntimeError in PetsController#monsters

--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
controller: pets
action: monsters

Rails.root: /home/eric/tobenamed.git/Trial
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/pets_controller.rb:17:in `monsters'

Request

Parameters:

None

Comment: Make raise params.to_yaml the first line of the controller action. What's the response? This should be an error message.